# It all works, but the button never becomes enabled

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

This all seems to work, but the button (bSaveNewTag) never becomes enabled. Going through it, I am guessing that countTag is not populated in time, but I don't get how to make it wait for a return value.

I have gone through with alerts which has made come to the above conclusion, but my knowledge of Javascript is very basic, so don't know what to do and when searching for answers, what I do find, I don't understand and can't figure out how to implement.

```
function checkIfNewTagExists(potentialTag) {
            var countTag = 0;

            $.ajax({
                url: "/CSC/api/checkTag/" + potentialTag + "/",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.map(data, function (item) {
                        countTag = parseInt(item.cTag, 10);
                    });
                },
                complete: function () {

                    if (countTag > 0) {
                        $('#newTag').css({ 'opacity': 1 });
                        $('#tbNewTagName').addClass("missing");
                    } else {
                        $('#newTag').css({ 'opacity': 0 });
                    }

                    return countTag;
                }
            });
        }

        function checkNewTag() {
            var countTag = 0;
            var potentialTag = '';
            var val = Page_ClientValidate("vgNewTag");
            var el = $("#bSaveNewTag")

            for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                if (Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                    $("#" + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).removeClass("missing");
                } else {
                    $("#" + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate).addClass("missing");
                }
            }

            potentialTag = $('#tbNewTagName').val();
            if (potentialTag == '') {
                countTag = 1;
            } else {
                countTag = checkIfNewTagExists(potentialTag);
            }

            if (val && countTag === 0) {
                el.prop("disabled", false);
            } else {
                el.prop("disabled", true);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You editied it out in the grace period, but still - do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working. It could also be helpful to look up how to create a [MCVE] - consider trimming out code that's not directly related to the problem.

Comment: The problem when you are using `ajax` in this manner is that, it never returns the result using the `return` keyword. You should try using callback functions instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Comment: You are enabling/disabling the button based on the result of `checkIfNewTagExists` which uses ajax. Your `return countTag;` doesn't really return the value by calling `checkIfNewTagExists`, it only returns the value to the one calling the `complete` callback function (which is the ajax call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not understand my comments above, or the article I referenced, here is the breakdown of what you should do.

```
function checkIfNewTagExists(potentialTag, callback) {
    var countTag = 0;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/CSC/api/checkTag/" + potentialTag + "/",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.map(data, function (item) {
                countTag = parseInt(item.cTag, 10);
            });
        },
        complete: function () {
            if (countTag > 0) {
               $('#newTag').css({ 'opacity': 1 });
                $('#tbNewTagName').addClass("missing");
            } else {
                $('#newTag').css({ 'opacity': 0 });
            }

            //return countTag;
            callback(countTag);
        }
    });
}
```

Then this part:

```
potentialTag = $('#tbNewTagName').val();
if (potentialTag == '') {
    countTag = 1;
} else {
    countTag = checkIfNewTagExists(potentialTag);
}

if (val && countTag === 0) {
    el.prop("disabled", false);
} else {
    el.prop("disabled", true);
    return false;
}
```

Should be (something) like this:

```
potentialTag = $('#tbNewTagName').val();
if (potentialTag == '') {
    countTag = 1;
    el.prop("disabled", true);
} else {
    //countTag = checkIfNewTagExists(potentialTag);
    checkIfNewTagExists(function(cTag){
        countTag = cTag;

        if (val && countTag === 0) {
            el.prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            el.prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
}
```

Now, I can see you have the `return false;` in the last `else` line of `checkNewTag`. If you intend to return something to the calling line, you should also use a callback function instead of `var x = checkNewTag();`